# Navigation for Aurelia router doesn't work

Tags: navigation, aurelia

I try to implement my own authentication and I save token in sessionStorage.
On each page I check:

```
 attached() {

        if (sessionStorage.getItem("token") == null) {
            console.log("sessionStorage null");
            this.theRouter.navigate("login");
        }
        console.log("continue on transactions");
....
}
```

As result - I see in console the message *sessionStorage null*, but navigate doesn't work and I see the message *continue on transactions* also.

My route in app.ts (main file) is the following:

```
config.map([{
            route: ['', 'home'], name: 'home', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../home/home'), nav: true, title: 'Home'
        },{
            route: 'transactions', name: 'transactions', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../transactions/transactions'), nav: true, title: 'Transactions'
        }, {
        route: 'login', name: 'login', moduleId: PLATFORM.moduleName('../auth/login'), nav: false, title: 'Login'
    }]);
```

How I can organize the correct redirect?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm gonna guess that a `return` statement after the call to `navigate` should stop execution of the function.

That being said...

You should look at using router pipeline hooks to do this to reduce code duplication: http://aurelia.io/hub.html#/doc/article/aurelia/router/latest/router-configuration/8

Here's an example directly from that link:

```
import {Redirect} from 'aurelia-router';

export class App {
  configureRouter(config, router) {
    var step = new AuthorizeStep;
    config.addAuthorizeStep(step)
    config.map([
      { route: ['', 'home'],       name: 'home',       moduleId: 'home/index' },
      { route: 'users',            name: 'users',      moduleId: 'users/index', settings: { auth: true } },
      { route: 'users/:id/detail', name: 'userDetail', moduleId: 'users/detail', settings: { auth: true } },
      { route: 'files/*path',       name: 'files',      moduleId: 'files/index',   href:'#files', nav: true }
    ]);
  }
}

class AuthorizeStep {
  run(navigationInstruction, next) {
    if (navigationInstruction.getAllInstructions().some(i => i.config.settings.auth)) {
      var isLoggedIn = // insert magic here;
      if (!isLoggedIn) {
        return next.cancel(new Redirect('login'));
      }
    }

    return next();
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your solutions. 
Unfortunately, I have repeated my problem after class AuthorizeStep adding.

I have solved the problem by following standard decision - I added _auth=true_ for each necessary route.